# I want to extrude a path to a cirleshape, how can i smooth out the corners. Bevel them doesn't work

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

[image: Screenshot]

I copied the path from a set of vertices; convert it to a curve and it's all weird shaped once i extrude them.
How to bevel them, on the corners, for example for a pipe.
an smooth out sections like on the upper- left corner.

ctrl- B doesent work.

Answer (score 2):

Your curve is a *Poly* curve. It's not very flexible. But you can convert it to a  *Nurbs* curve.

Edit the curve, select one vertice and set the *Spline Type* to *NURBS*. The path will become much more flexible.
[image: nurbs curve]

Now extrude (<kbd>E</kbd>) the path at both ends 1x to restore the length of the ends. Then subdivide the segments to add more vertices (menu *Segments > Subdivide*). Move the new vertices closer to the corner to control the curve radius and to create the shape that you want.

[image: extra vertices for the path]